# Does C pick the first matching .h file from a list of Include paths?

Tags: c, include

In a more perfect world, perhaps the compiler/linker would flag the ambiguity, but I don't think this is the case.  I was hoping someone would know.

to be more clear:

```
cc -c foo.c -Ithis_directory_contains_foo_h  -Iso_does_this_one
```

Comment: Yes, the include paths are searched in order.

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`c99`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)
specifies these things. _"Thus, headers whose names are enclosed in double-quotes ( `""` ) shall be searched for first in the directory of the file with the `#include` line, then in directories named in `-I` options, and last in the usual places. For headers whose names are enclosed in angle brackets ( `<>` ), the header shall be searched for only in directories named in `-I` options and then in the usual places. Directories named in `-I` options shall be searched in the order specified."_

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 6.10.2 2 specifies that an `#include` using `<name>``:

> … searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>` delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.

Compare this with 6.10.2 3 for an `#include` using `"name"``, which omits “identified uniquely”:

> … causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if [it used `<` and `>` instead of `"`].

Thus, with `<` and `>`, the header ought to be unique. However, the last sentence paragraph 2 offers great latitude; an implementation could say that the header is identified by being the first found with that name, which would uniquely identify it.

With `"`, the standard does not say the header should be uniquely identified, so it is generally not considered a problem if there are multiple headers with the same name.

Since how the places are searched and how the header is identified are implementation-defined, a compiler is free to search them in any order its authors choose, as long as they define it. For header directories specified in the command line, typical compilers search them in the order given on the command line. However, there may be complications with the way they interact with directories built into the compiler or specified via the environment.

Clang has switches `-isystemdirectory` to insert a directory at the start of the system search path (for `<` and `>` includes), `-isystemafterdirectory` to append a directory at the end of the system search path, `--include-directory-after=directory` to append a directory at the end of the regular search path, and more. Testing with Apple Clang 11 shows it does not complain if files with a requested `<` `>` header name exist in multiple directories being searched, even with `-Wall`.

Comment: You last sentence is interesting. I guess there is not much concern about this issue.